# XSLT calculations where grouping is on grand-children

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

i have a XML datadump from a database that i want to present using xslt.
The structure of the data is not 'straightforward' for the layout that i want (i also use the XML data for another report).

What i want is to do some calculations on data from Level-A where i need to group on Level-C children.

I know i can probably select the data again into an XML file where the structure is 'easy' for my report, but that is my last resort because i have the feeling that it can also be accomplished in XSLT itself. Most probbaly i need some 'Muenchian' trick to get it done, but since i am a 'Muenchian Virgin' i get stuck in every attempt (that i try to 'steal' and change ...).

Does anybody know if Muenchian is the way to proceed and can somebody help me to get on the right track ?
I did some reading (including Jeni Tennison's), but the stuff i have seen so far is not covering my problem as far as i know ...

Below is a simplified XML structure that is (more or less) representative for my real problem.

Any ideas?

Kind regards, Henk

## Simplyfied XML:

```
<data>
  <a>
    <a_id>A1</a_id>
    <a_desc>A one</a_desc>
    <a_val>1</a_val>
    <b>
      <c>
        <c_id>C2</c_id>
        <c_desc>C two</c_desc>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <a_id>A2</a_id>
    <a_desc>A two</a_desc>
    <a_val>2</a_val>
    <b>
      <c>
        <c_id>C2</c_id>
        <c_desc>C two</c_desc>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <a_id>A3</a_id>
    <a_desc>A three</a_desc>
    <a_val>3</a_val>
    <b>
      <c>
        <c_id>C1</c_id>
        <c_desc>C one</c_desc>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <a_id>A4</a_id>
    <a_desc>A four</a_desc>
    <a_val>7</a_val>
    <b>
      <c>
        <c_id>C3</c_id>
        <c_desc>C three</c_desc>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <a_id>A5</a_id>
    <a_desc>A five</a_desc>
    <a_val>11</a_val>
    <b>
      <c>
        <c_id>C1</c_id>
        <c_desc>C one</c_desc>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
</data>
```

## Required output should be something like:

```
C_desc  Count() Sum(a_val)  Avg(a_val) 
------  ------- ----------  ----------
C one       3       15          5
C two       1       2           2
C three     1       7           7
```

Comment: There is no element `c_val` in the provided XML document! What should be in the identically -named column of the result-table? *Please*, edit the question and correct.

Comment: Muenchian grouping is indeed the way to go in XSLT1.0. If you were able to use XSLT2.0 there are dedicated grouping functions available to make it easier. Are you able to use XSLT2.0?

Comment: @Dimitri: that was a little typo ... meant avg(a_val)
Note: i am using xslt 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, Muenchian grouping is the way to go (in XSLT1.0). You say you want to group **a** elements, using values in a **c** element. Therefore you would define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="a" match="a" use="b/c/c_desc" />
```

Then, you need to get 'distinct' **a** elements, which is done by selecting **a** elements that happen to be the first element in the group for a given key. You do this with this fairly scary expression

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="//a[generate-id() = generate-id(key('a', b/c/c_desc)[1])]" />
```

Here, `key('a', b/c/c_desc)[1]` will find the first element in the key's group, and then you use `generate-id` to compare the elements.

Then, you would have a template to match the distinct **a** elements, and within in this you can then do calculations on the group. For example, to get the sum:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('a', b/c/c_desc)/a_val)" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="a" match="a" use="b/c/c_desc" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>C_desc</td>
            <td>Count</td>
            <td>Sum</td>
            <td>Avg</td>
         </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//a[generate-id() = generate-id(key('a', b/c/c_desc)[1])]" />
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a">
      <xsl:variable name="c_desc" select="b/c/c_desc" />
      <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('a', $c_desc))" /></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('a', $c_desc)/a_val)" /></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('a', $c_desc)/a_val) div count(key('a', $c_desc))" /></td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>C_desc</td>
      <td>Count</td>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>Avg</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```